# Add or Remove Attribute using jQuery toggle to Hide / Show an item

Tags: jquery, toggle, attr

I have the following jQuery which I use to Hide/Show an iFrame when I click a button.

The iFrame contains some PHP, which I only want to load when the iFrame is displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#button').click(function()
            {
                $('#graphFrame').toggle().attr('src', 'graph1.php');    
            }
        )   
    }
);
```

This works fine, except that it also tries to load the PHP, when I hide the iFrame.

Is there a way to tell it to Add the 'src' attribute when I display the iFrame (and thus load the php), and remove it when I hide the iFrame (thus not loading the PHP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#graphFrame').toggle(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
    $this.is(":visible") ? $this.attr('src', 'graph1.php') : $this.removeAttr('src')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $('#graphFrame').toggle();
        $('#graphFrame:visible').attr('src', 'graph1.php');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var ifr = $('#graphFrame');
    ifr.toggle(function(){
        if(ifr.is(':visible')) ifr.attr('src', 'graph1.php');
        else ifr.attr('src', '');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/CJehy/1/)

Comment: thanks, I particularly like the fact that this one makes the graph slide into view.